# Filter an Array based off user input string and menu dropdown items

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am struggling to filter an array in one of my react projects.

My React App has a search bar that returns a searchQuery as a string and menu of movement patterns that when clicked gets added to the pattern array. 
The user should be able to:

1. type in a search query and filter the array
2. use the menu to select multiple pattern options to filter array
3. filter the exercise array with both search and menu selection.

```js
const searchQuery = "ben";
const pattern = [];

const exercises = [
  {
    name: "bench press",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "squat",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "squat",
    movement: ["squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "pushup",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "pullup",
    movement: ["pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "bent over row",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "hinge"]
  }
];

let filteredExercises = [];

if (searchQuery && pattern) {
  filteredExercises = exercises.filter(
    exercise =>
      exercise.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1 &&
      exercise.movement.some(movement =>
        pattern.some(pattern => pattern == movement)
      )
  );
} else if (pattern.length > 0) {
  filteredExercises = exercises.filter(exercise =>
    exercise.movement.some(movement =>
      pattern.some(pattern => pattern == movement)
    )
  );
} else if (searchQuery) {
  filteredExercises = exercises.filter(
    exercise => exercise.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1
  );
  console.log(filteredExercises);
}

console.log(filteredExercises);
```

The first two conditional statements work and return the correct data. As soon as I add the third conditional statement to filter by searchQuery I get an empty array in return.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `searchQuery && pattern` will always return true unless pattern is empty. You should use `searchQuery && pattern.length`

Comment: Thank you! Changing pattern to pattern.length worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think checking the array as a truthy value instead of the length of the array was your biggest issue.

However, I also think this could be written more simply by moving the repeated code to functions and just running one `filter`. If you don't like ternary operators you can replace what I have with your `if`/`if else` clauses (don't forget the returns though).

```js
const searchQuery = "ben";
const pattern = [];

const exercises = [
  {
    name: "bench press",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "squat",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "squat",
    movement: ["squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "pushup",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "pullup",
    movement: ["pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "bent over row",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "hinge"]
  }
];

const excerciseTest = (name, searchQuery) => {
  

return name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
}

const patternTest = (movement, pattern) => {
  return movement.some(movement => {
    return pattern.some(pattern => pattern === movement)
  })
}
         
const filteredExercises = exercises.filter(excercise => {

    // if (searchQuery && pattern.length > 0)
  return (searchQuery && pattern.length > 0)
    ? excerciseTest(excercise.name, searchQuery) && patternTest(excercise.movement, pattern)
    
    // else if (pattern.length > 0)
    : pattern.length > 0
    ? patternTest(excercise.movement, pattern)

    // else if (searchQuery)
    : searchQuery
    ? excerciseTest(excercise.name, searchQuery)
    : false
})

console.log(filteredExercises)
```

Comment: this was extremely helpful and enlightening. I appreciate your time and help!

Comment: Thanks @DanBoterashvili, happy to help! Would you mind accepting this as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

An empty array is *truthy* which means your first `if` is firing when `pattern` is empty — it never makes it to your last `else if`. You can test for `pattern.length` instead and it should work

```js
const searchQuery = "ben";
const pattern = [];

const exercises = [
  {
    name: "bench press",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "squat",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "squat",
    movement: ["squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "pushup",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "pullup",
    movement: ["pull", "squat", "hinge"]
  },
  {
    name: "bent over row",
    movement: ["push", "pull", "hinge"]
  }
];

let filteredExercises = [];

if (searchQuery && pattern.length) {
  filteredExercises = exercises.filter(
    exercise =>
      exercise.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1 &&
      exercise.movement.some(movement =>
        pattern.some(pattern => pattern == movement)
      )
  );
} else if (pattern.length > 0) {
  filteredExercises = exercises.filter(exercise =>
    exercise.movement.some(movement =>
      pattern.some(pattern => pattern == movement)
    )
  );
} else if (searchQuery) {
  filteredExercises = exercises.filter(
    exercise => exercise.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1
  );
  console.log(filteredExercises);
}

console.log(filteredExercises);
```